# Autosuggest/Combobox suggestion wont display

Tags: reactjs, components, autosuggest

For some reason the suggestion wont display, there are no error messages in console.

[image: combo box flow]

Senario

1. User clicks on combobox, suggestion are displayed. **(Working)**
2. User selects a suggestion. Suggestion is displayed in combobox.
   (Selection its loading in a single span)
3. If user clicks on combobox after making a selection, combobox will clear value, but previous selection will display as a highlighted first choice. Also updated suggestion display below first choice.
   ( I really need help on this one, I can see the data in the console log. But since the suggestions are not displaying I can tell if its displays as requested )

(see image for reference)

[react-autosuggest](https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest) react-autosuggest@9.3.4

Component Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM, { findDOMNode } from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classNames from "classnames";
import Autosuggest from "react-autosuggest";

import Icon from '../Components/Icons/Icons';

class Autocomplete extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      value: "",
      suggestions: [],
      isTouched: false,
      multi: false,
      selectedInput: ""
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.blurCallback = this.blurCallback.bind(this);
    this.triggerFocus = this.triggerFocus.bind(this);
    this.handleClear = this.handleClear.bind(this);
  }

  getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion.text;

  renderSuggestion = suggestion => (<span>{suggestion.text}</span>)

  escapeRegexCharacters = (str) => str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");

  getSectionSuggestions = section => section && section.items;

  getSuggestions = (value, selected, reason) => {
    let suggestions = this.props.data;

    if (value !== undefined) {
      const escapedValue = this.escapeRegexCharacters(value.trim());
      const selectedInput = [];
      selectedInput.push(selected);
      const regex = new RegExp(escapedValue, "i");
      const filtered = suggestions.filter(language =>
        regex.test(language.text)
      );

      if (escapedValue === "") {
        return {
          suggestions: [
            { text: selectedInput[0], items: [] },
            { text: "", items: filtered }
          ],
          multi: true
        };
      }

      if (!filtered.length) {
        return {
          suggestions: selectedInput.length > 0 ? selectedInput : filtered,
          multi: false
        };
      }

      return {
        suggestions: [{
            text: selectedInput[0],
            items: selectedInput.length > 0 ? selectedInput : filtered
          },
          {
            text: "",
            items: reason === "focused" ? suggestions : filtered
          }],
        multi: true
      };
    } else return;
  };

  onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({ value, reason }) => {
    if (reason === "input-focused") {
      this.setState({ value: "" });
      const { multi, suggestions } = this.getSuggestions(
        value,
        this.state.selectedInput ? this.state.selectedInput : "",
        "focused"
      );
      this.setState({
        suggestions,
        multi
      });
    } else {
      const { multi, suggestions } = this.getSuggestions(
        value,
        this.state.selectedInput ? this.state.selectedInput : "",
        "notfocused"
      );
      this.setState({
        suggestions,
        multi
      });
    }
  };

  onSuggestionsClearRequested = () => {
    this.setState({
      suggestions: [],
      multi: false
    });
  };

  onChange = (event, { newValue, method }) => {
    if (method === "enter") {
      this.setState({
        value: this.state.value
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        value: newValue
      });
    }

    if(this.props.search) {
      this.props.search(newValue, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode.parentNode.querySelectorAll('li'));
    };
  };

  onSuggestionSelected = (ev,
    { suggestion, suggestionValue, suggestionIndex, sectionIndex, method }
  ) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedInput: suggestionValue
    });
  };

  blurCallback (ev) {
    this.setState({  isTouched: false });
  }

  handleClear() {
    this.setState({
      value: ''
    })
  }
  onClick(ev) {
    this.setState({ isTouched: true });
  }

  triggerFocus() {
    const input = document.getElementById(this.props.id);
    input.focus();
  }

  render() {

    const theme = {
      container: "el-form",
      containerOpen: "react-autosuggest__container--open",
      input: "autocomplete form-control",
      inputOpen: "react-autosuggest__input--open",
      inputFocused: "react-autosuggest__input--focused",
      suggestionsContainer: "react-autosuggest__suggestions-container",
      suggestionsContainerOpen:
        "react-autosuggest__suggestions-container--open",
      suggestionsList: "autocomplete-wrap",
      suggestion: "react-autosuggest__suggestion",
      suggestionFirst: "react-autosuggest__suggestion--first",
      suggestionHighlighted: "react-autosuggest__suggestion--highlighted",
      sectionContainer: "react-autosuggest__section-container",
      sectionContainerFirst: "react-autosuggest__section-container--first",
      sectionTitle: "react-autosuggest__section-title"
    };

    const {
      className,
      placeholder,
      data,
      disabled,
      label,
      labelClass,
      icon,
      iconSize,
      iconClass,
      clear,
      clearClass,
      id,
      search,
      ...attributes
    } = this.props;

    const labelClassFix = classNames(
      isNotEmpty && "active",
      disabled && "disabled",
      labelClass
    );
    const iconClassFix = classNames(
      "prefix",
      this.state.isTouched && "active",
      iconClass
    );
    const clearClassFix = classNames(
      clearClass
    )

    const isclearVisible = () => {
      let hiddenOrNot = "hidden"
      if (this.state.value) {
        hiddenOrNot = "visible";
      }
      return hiddenOrNot;
    }
    const clearStyleFix = {
      position: "absolute",
      zIndex: 2,
      top: "2.5rem",
      right: "10px",
      border: "none",
      background: "0 0",
      visibility: isclearVisible(),
    }

    let isNotEmpty =
      Boolean(this.state.value) || placeholder || this.state.isTouched;

    const { value, suggestions, multi } = this.state;

    const inputProps = {
      placeholder: placeholder,
      value,
      onChange: this.onChange,
      onBlur: this.blurCallback,
      onClick: this.onClick,
      onFocus: this.onFocus,
      id: this.props.id,
      name: this.props.name
    };

    const renderInputComponent = inputProps => (
      <div>
        { icon && <Icon icon={icon} className={iconClassFix}/> }
        <input
          type="text"
          id={id}
          name={name}
          className="form-control"
          {...inputProps}
          onFocus={(ev, val) => {
            this.onClick();
            inputProps.onFocus(ev, val);
          }}
        />
        <label
          htmlFor={id}
          id={`label for ${id}`}
          onClick={this.triggerFocus}
          className={labelClassFix}
        >
          { label }
        </label>
        { clear &&
          <Icon icon="close" onClick={this.handleClear} style={clearStyleFix}
          className={clearClassFix}/>
        }
      </div>
    );

    return (
        <Autosuggest
          multiSection={multi}
          renderSectionTitle={this.renderSuggestion}
          getSectionSuggestions={this.getSectionSuggestions}
          suggestions={suggestions}
          highlightFirstSuggestion={true}
          focusInputOnSuggestionClick={false}
          onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
          onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
          getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
          renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
          inputProps={inputProps}
          theme={theme}
          renderInputComponent={renderInputComponent}
          shouldRenderSuggestions={ () => true }
          onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
        />
    );
  }
}

Autocomplete.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  icon: PropTypes.string,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
};

Autocomplete.defaultProps = {
  id: 'autocomplete-1',
  name: '',
  clear: true
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

In use Component

```
const states = [ "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illnois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming" ];

<Autocomplete
  data={states}
  label="Choose your state"
  icon="lightbulb"
  clear
  clearClass="grey-text" id="combobox-states" name="state-selection"
  className="mx-auto"
/>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ryxywxj12p)

Answer (score 0):

you need a `return` in some of your callbacks :

```
  getSuggestionValue = suggestion => {
    return suggestion;
  }

  getSectionSuggestions = (section) => {
    return section && section.items;
  }
```

### Edit

In `getSuggestions` you need to return an array directly, not an object.
see https://codesandbox.io/s/w04jpzjr4k

Comment: Meant to be a implicit return
`getSuggestionValue = suggestion => suggestion;`

Thanks for pointing that out, but still didn't work.

Comment: Could you reproduce the problem in https://codesandbox.io/s/new, and share the link with us

Comment: I see. I'll try those changes.